# Docker Spring active profile

Tags: java, spring, docker

i'm trying to set the active profile of my spring boot application, which runs in a docker container.
The docker container is created using the gradle jib plugin.

According to stackoverflow posts, that I have found it is possible to set the active profile with:
`-e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test"` or with `-e "spring.profiles.active=test`, but both options do not work for me. I always get the output: `No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"`.

Does somebody have an idea, why it does not apply the active profile?

My current docker command:

```
docker run -p 8888:8080 ...(the docker image)... \
      -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test" \
      -e "spring.profiles.active=test" \
      -e "...additional spring environments..."
```

I sadly do not have a dockerfile, but this are the envs and the entrypoint from docker inspect:

```
"Env": [ "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
         "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
         "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
         "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
         "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.16.1+1",
         "LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
       ],
"Entrypoint": [
        "java",
        "-cp",
        "@/app/jib-classpath-file",
        "my.organization.MyApplication"
 ],
```

Comment: the image might not be passing the environment variables to the java process, if possible post the dockerfile.

Comment: In your question you have `docker run image-name -e ...`.  Docker-specific arguments like `-e` need to go _before_ the image name; anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run (with that entrypoint setup, you would see the `-e` options in the array parameter to your `main()` function).

Comment: Thank you very much, putting the environments before the image fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try with `spring-boot.run.profiles`.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-profiles)
and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#profiles).

Comment: Adding `-e "spring-boot.run.profiles=test"` does not work, or should I put this somewhere else ?

Comment: As @David Maze mentioned, you need to put options (in your case -e) right after the run command as described here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file